# Flutter IOS blank screen

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I have a flutter app i have developed and it is running efficiently on a real device with zero errors or warnings in debug mode. however when i deploy a release to the same real device it produces a white screen on most pages. I am producing the release using X-code. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

connect your device using cable.

then write following command in terminal.

- flutter run

to see error log in terminal in red colors.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open Terminal and Go to ***/ios*** folder inside your project.
2. Executes **pod deintegrate** command.
3. Then after **pod install**
4. Run your project **Flutter run**